# Replication study and Bayes factor

Tags: bayesian, cohens-d, bayes-factors, replicability

I ran an experiment and got a statistically significant result with an effect size of cohen's d=0.36 (N=20). I decided to run a replication study, this time with 60 participants, and got nothing (d=0.02). I want to compute a Bayes factor for the ratio between the likelihoods of my data under the effect size as predicted by the first experiment and under the null hypothesis (no effect).
I was thinking of something along the lines of

```
 BF = dnorm(new_cohens_d, old_cohens_d, std1)/dnorm(new_cohens_d, 0, std2)
```

but I can't wrap my head around what should be the standard deviations of the two distributions. Would 1/sqrt(60) make sense here?

Comment: What are d and d' as mentioned above.  Statistical significance is based on a low p-value, commonly p < 0.05.

Comment: Hi Michael, sorry for not making this clear enough - these are the cohen's d effect sizes.

Comment: @MichaelChernick The OP is obviously heading towards a Bayesian analysis so p-values will neither be needed nor be usefull.

Comment: This uses `srqt(N)` as well: http://bayesfactor.blogspot.de/2014/02/bayes-factor-t-tests-part-1.html

Answer (score 1):

I was kindly referred by Dan Kassler to this very useful paper, that approaches exactly this question:
http://psycnet.apa.org/psycinfo/2014-21247-001/
The authors cite this paper that I also found useful:
http://search.proquest.com/docview/228434917?pq-origsite=gscholar